# Use a xref of values to sub into tuple based on value - Python

Tags: python

I have a list of xref values

```
internal_customer = {'01':'11', '03':'33', '05':'55', '07':'77', '08':'88', '06':'66', '09':'22', '11':'18', '12':'19'}
```

that I would like to use to sub a value in a tuple:

```
('03', 'S/N A1631703')
```

So my resulting tuple would be

```
('33', 'S/N A1631703')
```

Can someone point me in the direction of the tools I could use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpack and access the dict using the first element, presuming you have an list of tuples:

```
internal_customer = {'01':'11', '03':'33', '05':'55', '07':'77', '08':'88', '06':'66', '09':'22', '11':'18', '12':'19'}

lst = [('03', 'S/N A1631703'),('05', 'S/N A1631703')]

lst[:] = ((internal_customer[a], b) for a,b in t)    
print(t)
```

tuples are immutable so there is no notion of mutating, you have to create a new tuple comprising of the new value from the dict and the existing second element. The `lst[:]` syntax at least allows you to modify the original list. You can of course just reassign the name or create a completely new list if you want to maintain the original.

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries, you might want to consider using a list in place of tuples if you are going to be modifying a lot if the logic of your code allows it.

Comment: I have a list of tuples that I'm subbing in the values from the xref dict to.  It's a list of results from a pyodbc fetchall.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Ah ok, don't sweat it then, I thought it may be something you had control over creating.